# PHP Button Count

Tags: php, database, count, click

I'm just wondering how to count a unique click - to check the IP (not one person make 1k clicks). I viewed some scripts here and in other websites, but they aren't the specific thing I search for. I search only for script to count the clicks (without connecting to the DB) and than write them in HTML.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Thanks for the -3 support =) ... -_-

I know I want it ready, but I'm designer, not programmer...

Comment: Google is a good place to start

Comment: Man, u think I'm a 5 year old kid, and don't check it? I just needED it fast...

Comment: man, u think we R here to work 4 u?

Comment: Somebody oblige you to help me? You have full rights to pass the topic :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a connection with a DB, you got other solutions like:

- log all the clicks to a text file (very bad way, example here: http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/text-file-hit-counter )
- search for some site that offers to you this service. I do not even know if you can find something like this out there (google is your friend).

Comment: Thanks for the paid attention...